# Heroku PostgreSQL: Restart adds duplicate lines

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, heroku

I have a spring boot application running on Heroku with PostgreSQL addon. Upon start spring boot creates automatically some dummy data into PostgreSQL such as *users* and their *contact information*. Tables and insert statements are stored in `Schema.sql` [(pastebin)](https://pastebin.com/4pZwdZbT) and `Data.sql` [(pastebin)](https://pastebin.com/7RbUxB8N)

On first launch everything works fine, but after I restart it spring boot application creates the same rows again and this results to an error for having duplicates lines, duplicate relations and so on.

How can I disable data recreation on restart?

Heroku **Config Vars** are set to:

[image]

Each SQL insert statement has **ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING** and each create table statement has **IF NOT EXISTS**

Comment: "Upon start spring boot creates automatically some dummy data"—why are you doing this when your application starts in the first place?

Comment: @Chris Because I want some data to exists at launch. It is basically there to someone see how everything looks when application is in use.

Comment: Right, but why when the application _starts_? Wouldn't it make more sense to do that as part of your deploy or, better yet, seed it explicitly by running a script? This sounds like a one-time task, not something that should happen every day (Heroku dynos restart frequently). Or, depending on the data, maybe it belongs in a database migration.

Comment: @Chris I want the data to be always the same when application starts. This way when participants add their own stuff there it will get deleted at some point in time when Dyno restarts. Whole point is to show "starting" data and that starting data should always be there after each restart. Even when user decides to mess with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While @richyen has identified the problem correctly, I would suggest a different solution: Fix your schema and use [natural keys](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_key) for your users instead of (or at least, in addition to) the [surrogate `serial` key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surrogate_key).

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users(
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  username varchar(255) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
--                      ^^^^^^
  email varchar(255) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
--                   ^^^^^^
  PASSWORD varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  enabled INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
  created_at TIMESTAMP,
  modified_at TIMESTAMP,
  removed_at TIMESTAMP
);
```

<sub>(A `PRIMARY KEY` is exactly the same as `UNIQUE NOT NULL`, except that you can have it only once and it gets to be the default for foreign key references to the table that don't explicitly specify the column).</sub>

This will cause the expected conflicts when you try to insert users with the same names or email addresses.

Comment: I did what you @Bergi said and it worked like richyen said. I upvoted both answers and selected this one as the answer since it solved my problem.

Comment: That's a good point--unique constraints on "things that matter."  I'll be sure to add that to my list of things to suggest :D

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that even though you specify `ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING`, you don't specify an `id` column on your `INSERT` statements.  This is not necessarily a bad thing, but basically it nullifies your `ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING` clause (at least for the sake of the startup sequence).  You will never encounter a conflict because the `id` column is a serial and it is your primary key.  Therefore, if you don't explicitly name it in your `INSERT` statement, the database will happily add another row with the "next" value of that `id` sequence, along with the other columns named in your `INSERT`.  A conflict only happens when you encounter a situation where you would have two identical values for a primary key, and in your `Data.sql`, you will never reach that situation.

If you really want the `ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING` behavior, then you need to add an `id` column in your `INSERT`s, and then be sure to set your sequences with `setval()`, so that new rows generated by your app aren't inadvertently dropped/ignored because of `id` conflict.

The other option (if your data set is ONLY for development) is to truncate your tables so you get a clean working data set every time (but that depends on what your requirements are).  If you do this, then you would need to also reset your sequences, so that your `id`s don't just keep growing forever.

Finally, you could just set `SPRING_DATASOURCE_INITIALIZATION_MODE = Never` now that you have loaded the seed data in.  Again, that's just a decision you need to make based on your requirements.